# Encrypting Files With A Certificate

Tags: encryption, file-encryption

**I am hunting for a solution where I can send someone encrypted files and a digital certificate that allows them to open the file.**
The reason for doing it this way is because:

- I don't want to keep giving them a new password every-time I send
  them some newly encrypted files, and they cannot keep up with a password because of staff changes and security reasons.

I know you can encrypt files in Adobe Acrobat with a certificate but the files I am trying to encrypt are not documents, more like scripts, programs, etc.

Comment: If you'd send these people a "certificate" that's reusable for decrypting files, why not just simply reuse the same password?

Comment: They have very limited technical knowledge, I need the decryption to be transparent

Comment: Then you'll probably want to use, say, a zip/rar self-extracting archive that asks for the password.

Comment: thats what I would say too but the requirement is to use a certificate, I tried using Kleopatra but you still have to use a password to open the file everytime

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://www.encryptedsend.com/.

Comment: Kleopatra allows you to leave an empty passphrase when creating a gpg key (it warns you that this might not be a good idea, but allows it). In that case, no password is required when decrypting.

Comment: Just a point of clarification: A certificate contains only a **public** key, which can be used to encrypt but not to decrypt. If you want to do encryption using certificates. the recipient generates their own **public/private key pair**, and sends you the public key (either wrapped in a certificate or just "bare"). You then encrypt to their public key, and they use the **private** key to decrypt. If you send somebody an encrypted file and also the certificate (but *not* the private key), they can't do anything with it at all!

Answer (score 1):

Veracrypt has an option to use a keyfile instead of a password.  This allows the recipient of the encrypted file to not have to keep up with a password but can use a file (which is also encrypted) to decrypt the data.